# How can I make my console application call a function when a key is pressed?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have the following:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

    }
}
```

Is there a simple way that I can make this wait for a key to be pressed and then call a function. For example: call `function funcA()` if an "a" is pressed, `funcB()` if a "b" is pressed or exit if an "e" is pressed?

Comment: Hmm, well sorry but I just wanted to put in something to start with. If someone can give me a clue then I am happy to try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use this code `Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: I'am happy to help you Gemma that's normal

Comment: Thanks Candie. I will mark your answer as accepted. I like the other answer also but after checking what you said I found the same example as in the quoted text.

Answer (score 5):

```
var c = Console.ReadKey();

switch (c.KeyChar)
{
   case 'a':
      funcA();
      break;
   case 'b':
      funcB();
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**MSDN** : [Console.ReadKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx) - Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The pressed key is displayed in the console window.

You can do like this -- just need to replace the key value over here with the key you 
want...that will do work for you

```
public static void Main() 
   {
      ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
      // Prevent example from ending if CTL+C is pressed.
      Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

      Console.WriteLine("Press any combination of CTL, ALT, and SHIFT, and a console key.");
      Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
      do 
      {
         cki = Console.ReadKey();
         Console.Write(" --- You pressed ");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0) Console.Write("ALT+");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) != 0) Console.Write("SHIFT+");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) Console.Write("CTL+");
         Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());
       } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
```